# jspdf & CKEditor - .createObjectURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2pdf

While trying to use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) I'm getting the error

```
Error in function saveAs: n(...).createObjectURL is not a function
```

My code is simple:

HTML

```
    <button class="generatePdf"> click me </button>
```

JS

```
    //Generate PDF
    $(document).on('click', '.generatePdf', function() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20,20,'Some dummy text');
        doc.save('print.pdf')
    });
```

I used it in Laravel with Bower and Elixir (gulp) but I get the same error:

```
Error in function FileSaver@http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js:5875:18: get_URL(...).createObjectURL is not a function
```

if using

```
    <script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

I am accepting alternatives to [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) if you got any.
It happens in both Firefox 44.0.2 and Chromium 48.0.2564.116

Comment: I was looking at this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/143 and found that problem was that CKEditor had definend `URL` object. Commenting out ckeditor made everything work. However I need the CKEditor so I'm still working on this.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/143) issue I inserted the given code

```
    <script>(function () {
            var _createObjectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL;
            Object.defineProperty(window.URL, 'createObjectURL', {
                set: function (value) {
                    console.trace('set createObjectURL')
                    _createObjectURL = value;
                },
                get: function () {
                    console.trace('get createObjectURL')
                    return _createObjectURL;
                }
            })
        })();
        (function () {
            var _URL = window.URL;
            Object.defineProperty(window, 'URL', {
                set: function (value) {
                    console.trace('set URL')
                    _URL = value;
                },
                get: function () {
                    console.trace('get URL')
                    return _URL;
                }
            })
        })();  </script>
```

and found out the problem was in `eqneditor` plugin of `CKEditor`. I removed the plugin and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with unsetting the global URL:

```
    let oldURL = undefined;
    if (URL) {
        oldURL = URL;
        URL = undefined;
    }
    // file saving code
    if (oldURL) {
        URL = oldURL;
    }
```